# How to make a partially visible item clickable in viewpager2?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder, android-viewpager2

I have a ViewPagerV2 which allows me to show a whole item and partially another two before and after that whole one.
In code it looks like

```
viewPager.apply {
    clipToPadding = false
    clipChildren = false
    val recyclerView = (getChildAt(0) as RecyclerView)
    recyclerView.clipChildren = false
    recyclerView.overScrollMode = RecyclerView.OVER_SCROLL_ALWAYS
    recyclerView.itemAnimator = null
    offscreenPageLimit = 2
    addItemDecoration(
        MyDecoration(context.dip2px(BANNERS_MARGIN_IN_DP))
    )
}
```

The only clickable item is the entire visible element.
My goal is to make partially visible elements clickable. Is it possible?